# Select ALL checkboxes in t:selectManyCheckbox

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, checkbox, selectmanycheckbox

I have created  web-application using JSF 2.0 where I have many checkboxes. I want to select those checkboxes on clicking Select All Checkbox.

I have below code

```
<t:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{UserRegistration.selectAll}" onclick="selectAll(this)" />

<t:selectManyCheckbox value="#{UserRegistration.pagesSelected}" layout="pageDirection"  layoutWidth="4">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="registerForPatentss" itemLabel="Register New Applicant"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="success" itemLabel="Register New Project" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="getReportss" itemLabel="Project Reports" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="searhPatentss" itemLabel="Search For Project" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="addUserss" itemLabel="Add User Account" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="logPatentSystemss" itemLabel="System Log" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="userlistss" itemLabel="Details Of Registered Users" />
</t:selectManyCheckbox>
```

javascript is

```
<script language="javascript">
    function selectAll(checkbox) {
        alert('called me == ' + checkbox.checked);

        var elements = checkbox.form.elements;
        if (checkbox.checked==true) {
            alert('selecting all');
            for (var i = 0; i &lt; elements.length; i++) {
                var element = elements[i];
                alert('selecting all ' + element.checked + '==' + element.id + '==');
                if (/checkboxId$/.test(element.id)) {
                    alert('inside...')
                    element.checked = checkbox.checked;
                }
            }
        }
     }
</script>
```

However it is not working.

For testing I added `alert('selecting all ' + element.checked + '==');` however for this I get output as `selecting all ====` i.e. I don't get data for `element.id`.

When I change `<t:selectManyCheckbox` to `<h:selectManyCheckbox` I get value.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

### Edit 1

HTML generated output is

```
<table id="favNumber4">
<tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="favNumber4" checked="checked" value="1" />&#160;Joomla Websites (Fahim M Parkar)</label></td><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="favNumber4" checked="checked" value="2" />&#160;iPhone Application (Fahim M Parkar)</label></td></tr>
<tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="favNumber4" checked="checked" value="3" />&#160;Project 001 (New Applicant Two)</label></td><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="favNumber4" value="4" />&#160;Project 002 (New Applicant Two)</label></td></tr>
<tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="favNumber4" value="5" />&#160;Project 003 (New Applicant Two)</label></td><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="favNumber4" value="6" />&#160;Project 004 (New Applicant Two)</label></td></tr>
<tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="favNumber4" value="7" />&#160;PP1 (Testing Applicant)</label></td><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="favNumber4" value="8" />&#160;PP2 (Testing Applicant)</label></td></tr>
<tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="favNumber4" value="9" />&#160;TA - PR001 (Testing Applicant)</label></td><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="favNumber4" value="10" />&#160;XXXXX 1 (XXXXX)</label></td></tr>
```

### Edit 2

Note that I also have more checkboxes as below.

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{UserRegistration.rightSelected}" id="myRight">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="add" itemLabel="Add"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="delete" itemLabel="Delete" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="edit" itemLabel="Edit" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="invite" itemLabel="Invite For Projects" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Comment: If you want help with javascript, much better to post what the browser gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what I had....

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function selectAllProjects() {
        var iLen=userRegisterForm.elements.length;
        for (var i=0; i&lt;iLen; i++) {
            if (document.userRegisterForm.elements[i].type == "checkbox" &amp;&amp; document.userRegisterForm.elements[i].value>=1) {
                document.userRegisterForm.elements[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    }

    function deselectAllProjects() {
        var iLen=userRegisterForm.elements.length;
        for (var i=0; i&lt;iLen; i++) {
            if (document.userRegisterForm.elements[i].type == "checkbox" &amp;&amp; document.userRegisterForm.elements[i].value>=1) {
                document.userRegisterForm.elements[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }

</script>


| <a onclick="selectAllProjects();">Select All</a> |
<a onclick="deselectAllProjects();">Clear All</a> |
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the server side, but in your client code:

```
> <script language="javascript">
```

The language attribute was deprecated in HTML 4 and is removed from HTML5. The type attribute is required in HTML 4 and optional in HTML5. It can be set to `type="text/javascript"`, though in practice it's not necessary.

```
>     function selectAll(checkbox) {
>         alert('called me == ' + checkbox.checked);
> 
>         var elements = checkbox.form.elements;
>         if (checkbox.checked==true) {
```

The checked property is boolean, so you can just do:

```
          if (checkbox.checked) {
```

and so on. Perhaps simpler to just loop over the elements and set checkboxes to the same "checkedness" as *checkbox*, e.g.

```
  var checked = checkbox.checked;

  for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if (elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
      elements[i].checked = checked;
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Your solution will work, but the problem is I have two 4 set of Textboxes. By your solution, it will select all checkboxes in the FORM WHICH is not what I wanted. Only that section checkboxes should be selected....

Comment: The `<script type>` attribute is optional since HTML5 and defaults to `text/javascript`.

Comment: @BalusC—thanks, strange that it defaults to an obsolete media type. I wonder why the authors didn't specify application/javascript or application/ecmascript.